# Use of bootstrap with images that must resize between viewports

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitters Bootstrap grid system to create a site header like the example below:

[image: How it looks in any viewport above tablet]

This all works fine until you begin reducing the size of the screen in which case the title of the page and logo merge together like this:

[image: How it looks in a phones viewport]

Ideally I would like the end result to look like this when in a phone viewport:

[image: How it should look in a very small viewport]

---

### Here is my current code

**HTML**

```
<div class="pull-left fullWidth container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="classHeader col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
            <img class="pull-right smallLogo" src="http://identityview.net/wp-content/themes/identityview/templates/Corporate-Logo-With-Flower-Motif-single.png" />
            <h3 class="fifteenPxSpacing pull-left bottomAlign">My New Title</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
  .classHeader
  {
      position: relative; 
      padding: 0;
      height: 120px;
      width: 100%;
      margin: 40px 0 0 0;
      border: 1px solid black;
  }

  .smallLogo
  {
      height: 115px;
      width: 180px;
      padding: 10px;
  }

  .fullWidth
  {
      width: 100%;
  }

  .bottomAlign
  {
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: 0;
  }

  .fifteenPxSpacing
  {
     margin: 15px;
  }
```

And [here is a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zj9v81t7/2/) so that you can see exactly what is going on when you resize the browser to smallest.

Im aware that different browsers allow different minimum browser sizes in desktops, laptop etc so for reference im using Firefox 35.0

---

### What I have tried

I tried setting the bootstrap columns to two as opposed to one column where each would have 50% of the row each but this didnt work.

```
<div class="pull-left fullWidth container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="classHeader col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12"> //setting as one containing row first
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12"><img class="pull-right smallLogo" src="http://identityview.net/wp-content/themes/identityview/templates/Corporate-Logo-With-Flower-Motif-single.png" /></div> //then attempting to break into two columns within parent row
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12"><h3 class="fifteenPxSpacing pull-left bottomAlign">My New Title</h3></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @BillyMoat I would prefer the title to be below the image on resize and when in full size be bottom aligned with the image where the title is on the left and image on the right. Thanks though :)

Comment: What you are trying to achieve needs some logic behind for each breakpoint, which you can do using media queries. I would start this way http://jsfiddle.net/664pjkjk/4/ I hope it helps!

Comment: @Teknotica This would be a great solution but unfortunately the image I am using is a little big and requires reduction in order to fit inside the header container with the title when screen is resized. Swapnil's answer below is most similar to what I require. Thank you for the fiddle :)

Comment: You can always resize the logo using media queries, I would suggest using CSS sprites so you swap a new image that is mobile optimised. Currently your images is resizing to a point where the text is unreadable. Good luck!

Comment: @Teknotica That sounds intriguing, could you possibly provide an example? Thanks

Comment: KyleT check this link out. It's a great example of responsive logos http://www.responsivelogos.co.uk/ You can see what I was mentioned with media queries to swap images at the end of the CSS file http://www.responsivelogos.co.uk/style.css

Comment: Thats really very helpful and kind of you to find that for me :) Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your need to add the media query for this : also see the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zj9v81t7/9/

```
@media screen and (max-width:640px){

.fifteenPxSpacing {
    margin: 5px;
}    

 .pull-left {
    right: 0;
}   


}
```

Comment: This a good answer! Do you know if Bootstrap already does this within their framework? I dont want to add code where it exists already. Thanks.

Comment: yes media query is already there but the css written inside it ,is not there.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the col-xs-* classes to logo and header then it will be increased and decreased as per screen size. That i have done in my updated code you can check fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/swapnilmotewar/zj9v81t7/6/

```
     .classHeader
        {
            position: relative; 
            padding: 0;
            height: 120px;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 40px 0 0 0;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }

      .smallLogo{
          width: 100%;
          height: 115px;
          padding: 10px;
       
      }

      .fullWidth
      {
          width: 100%;
      }

      .bottomAlign
      {
        position: absolute; 
        bottom: 0;
      }

        .fifteenPxSpacing
        {
            margin: 15px;
        }
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.1.2/d3.min.js"></script>
    <div class="pull-left fullWidth container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="classHeader col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
             <div class="col-xs-6  pull-right ">
                 <img class="smallLogo" src="http://identityview.net/wp-content/themes/identityview/templates/Corporate-Logo-With-Flower-Motif-single.png" />
             </div>
             
                <h3 class="fifteenPxSpacing pull-left bottomAlign col-xs-6">My New Title</h3>
             
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: also for image tag not to set any height is good practice that image not going to distort.